# How to install VirtualBox SDK on Mac

Tags: python, macos, virtual-machine, virtualization, virtualbox

There does not seem to be any documentation on how to do it.  I went into `/sdk/installer` and ran the `vboxsetup.py` script but it raised the following exception:

```
Exception: No VBOX_INSTALL_PATH defined, exiting
```

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, it's a software application question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is really annoying that they don't adequately explain how to install it and it's weird that the virtualbox installation does not create the VBOX_INSTALL_PATH variable by itself.
Anyways, This is what worked for me:

```
export VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=/usr/lib/virtualbox
sudo -E python vboxapisetup.py install
```

Comment: Thanks, it is also valid for Ubuntu !

Comment: for my MacOS it was: `/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/sdk`

Answer (score 1):

this is a minimal example for running the Python demo script `vboxshell.py` from the VirtualBox SDK via the *Object Oriented Web Service for Python*.

Tested with:

- System: macOS 10.15.2
- VirtualBox version: 6.0.14

Instructions:

- install VirtualBox for macOS
- download SDK from the VirtualBox website (i.e. https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.0/VirtualBoxSDK-6.1.0-135406.zip) and extract to `$HOME/vboxtest/sdk`
- `mkdir $HOME/vboxtest`
- create a python2 venv:

```
cd $HOME/vboxtest
virtualenv venv_vbox -p python2
source venv_vbox/bin/activate
```

- install dependencies into the venv:

```
wget https://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/pyxml/pyxml/0.8.4/PyXML-0.8.4.tar.gz
pip install PyXML-0.8.4.tar.gz
pip install ZSI
```

- disable auth (for testing): `VBoxManage setproperty websrvauthlibrary null`
- install SDK python module:

```
cd $HOME/vboxtest/sdk/installer
export VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=/usr/local/bin/virtualbox
export VBOX_SDK_PATH=$HOME/vboxtest/sdk
python vboxapisetup.py install
```

- start API webserver: `/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/vboxwebsrv -t 0`
- start the actual demo script:

```
cd $HOME/vboxtest
source venv_vbox/bin/activate
cd $HOME/vboxtest/sdk/bindings/glue/python/sample
export VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=/usr/local/bin/virtualbox
export VBOX_SDK_PATH=$HOME/vboxtest/sdk
python vboxshell.py -w
```

You should be getting a virtualbox shell, in which you can i.e. list all vms:

```
$ python vboxshell.py -w
Running VirtualBox version 6.0.14
vbox>
vbox>list
    Machine 'tmp_default_1572559409192_87222' [32844f81-f971-42f8-99d8-f3edbf0bf637], machineState=PoweredOff, sessionState=Unlocked
    Machine 'c4-2' [891a3509-fbc5-44be-816d-5045dd626157], machineState=PoweredOff, sessionState=Unlocked
vbox>
```

For more infos check the SDK docs: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/SDKRef.pdf

(IMHO should be used with caution as both Python2 and ZSI are EOL).

Answer (score 0):

Five years later, things haven't progressed much it seems.

Under Mojave, I had brew installed python2 (2.7.15) and python3 (3.7.0), and I had to do the following:

```
cd /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/sdk/installer
sudo VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS /usr/local/bin/python2 vboxapisetup.py install
sudo VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS python3 vboxapisetup.py install
```

The built-in Mojave version of Python (`/usr/bin/python` version 2.7.10) was the only one that could `import vboxapi` after the VirtualBox install.  I had to add the other Python versions manually.

The only instruction regarding this that I could find comes on page 40 of the SDK ref, where it suggests:

```
# cd VBOX_INSTALL_PATH/sdk/installer
# PYTHON vboxapisetup.py install
```

But, of course no mention of an environment variable.  As Tal points out in the accepted answer, interesting that they can be bothered to write a 440 page SDK manual, and yet fail to mention this.

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple approach using virtual environs

I *try* to only use python 3.  For pyvbox API on Mac OS I'm using a second virtualenv which is python 2 [Python2 venv](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215489338-Installing-and-using-virtualenv-with-Python-2)

Base set up:

```
cd /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/sdk/installer
export VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS
sudo -E python3 vboxapisetup.py
cd $HOME
mkdir vbox
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python venvpy2
source venvpy2/bin/activate
pip install virtualbox
```

I still pretty much only use python3,  then use `subprocess.Popen` initialise `venvpy2` and run `python2` module.  Take `stdout` and `stderr` back into main controlling `python3` code.  Having got this to work,  I've concluded better approach for my use case is use command line `vboxmanage` [Automate box server setup](https://www.andreafortuna.org/2019/10/24/how-to-create-a-virtualbox-vm-from-command-line/)